# Meaning of AucTeX warning here

Tags: auctex, warning

I've created the following LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\subfile{./tex/title.tex}
\subfile{./tex/intro.tex} %warning here says: User Regex: /intro.. [44]
\subfile{./tex/dynamic.tex}
\subfile{./tex/tournament.tex}
\subfile{./tex/ltt.tex}
\subfile{./tex/experiments.tex}
\subfile{./tex/conclusion.tex}
\subfile{./tex/references.tex}
\end{document}
```

Why is that warning being displayed there, and what exactly does it mean? Should I be concerned, and how do I make it go away?

Comment: Searching on the Internet for "User regex:" I found the [manual of ChkTeX](http://www.nongnu.org/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf).  Are you using it?

Comment: Indeed, it's not AUCTeX that warns you, it's chktex.  Flycheck automatically runs chktex on LaTeX sources, and you can run it manually with `C-c C-c`.   By and large, though, it's not really an Emacs issue, but a problem of your chktex configuration file.